# How to set picklist value in URLFOR?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, picklist, urlfor

I'm trying to set a picklist value in URLFOR.

I have a custom button and when the button is pressed the following javascript is executed:

```
window.parent.open("{!URLFOR( $Action.Custom_Object__c.New,null,[CF00M0N00000OpQRx = Account.Name, CF00NK0000001jyxH = {!URLENCODE(TEXT(Account.Schedule__c))}, CF00N2a000000b34C = Account.Custom_Number_Field __c])}", "_self");
```

In the first scenario:
`CF00NK0000001jyxH = ''`
I receive the following error:

> Error: Field Account.Schedule__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

In the second scenario:
`CF00NK0000001jyxH = Account.Schedule__c`
I receive the following error:

> Error: Field Account.Schedule__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

In the third scenario:
`CF00NK0000001jyxH = TEXT(Account.Schedule__c)`
I receive the following error:

> Error: Field Account.Schedule__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

In the forth scenario:
`CF00NK0000001jyxH = {!URLENCODE(TEXT(Account.Schedule__c))}`
I receive the following error:

> Error: Syntax error

Could you please advise how to set a picklist value in URLFOR function?

Comment: What is the final URL you're trying to achieve?

Comment: In the new page I just need to set a picklist value coming from the parent object.

Comment: N.B. - the `CF....` fieldnames, if new to the sandbox, may not be the same as you promote into other orgs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put a merge field inside a merge field. As you have it now, you have this:

```
{! ... {! ... } ... }
```

This will confuse the compiler and result in the last error you received.

You also shouldn't need URLENCODE-- everything inside of `[]` is taken care of for you automatically.

As near as I can tell, this should work:

```
window.parent.open(
    "{!URLFOR(
        $Action.Custom_Object__c.New,
        null,
        [
            CF00M0N00000OpQRx=Account.Name, 
            CF00NK0000001jyxH=TEXT(Account.Schedule__c), 
            CF00N2a000000b34C=Account.Custom_Number_Field __c
        ]
    )}", 
    "_self");
```

I've added the newlines for clarity, but they're certainly not necessary.